# How to snap a view to the top edge of a software keyboard when it slides out?

Tags: android

I have some views that I want to always be visible, however, when the keyboard slides up, it covers the view in the bottom of the screen. What I want is to move that view up and snap the the top edge of the software keyboard. How can I key software keyboard's height and position?

My activity configuration is

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

and that I cannot change.

**UPDATE**

I cannot set `adjustResize` because there are too many visual elements on the screen, so if the screen size shrinks two times vertically, the layout will look screwed.

Comment: The only way to do this is to use `adjustResize` instead of `adjustPan`. Can you explain why you need `adjustPan`? Maybe there's a way to work around that requirement.

Comment: Tenfour04, I have edited my answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just wrap the area you want to pan into a scroll view?

Comment: Give the scroll view `android:fillViewport="true"` and `android:scrollbars="false"` so without keyboard it just looks and acts as if it's not there, and when the keyboard is on screen, the user doesn't know it's a scroll view.

Answer (score -1):

you should use

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"

take a look at [windowSoftInputMode documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for the meaning of all the options

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have mentioned in my initial post that this is not an acceptable solution for me